# How to include HTML/JS widget to reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, widget, tradingview-api

I'm trying to display the [TradingView widget](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/crypto-mkt-screener/?fbclid=IwAR2lds7AtJx8uTt6j14PUiOs3o6RoVV_zLb-BtEOYc0m0VJYFgQNUQQzbpI) in my ReactJS app but none of the methods I've tried worked.

The code I'm trying to include :

```
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-all/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Cryptocurrency Markets</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-screener.js" async>
  {
  "width": 1000,
  "height": 490,
  "defaultColumn": "overview",
  "screener_type": "crypto_mkt",
  "displayCurrency": "USD",
  "colorTheme": "light",
  "transparency": false,
  "locale": "en"
}
  </script>
</div>
```

Tried to render using :
`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: THECODE }} />`

Tried to render like this:

```
  <div className="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <div className="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-all/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">
  <span className="blue-text">Cryptocurrency Markets</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  {this.loadScript('https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-screener.js')}
</div>
```

using this loadScript function :

```
loadScript = function(src) {
    var tag = document.createElement(`script`, {
      width: 1000,
      height: 490,
      defaultColumn: "overview",
      screener_type: "crypto_mkt",
      displayCurrency: "USD",
      colorTheme: "light",
      transparency: false,
      locale: "en",
    });
    tag.async = true;
    tag.type = 'text/javascript';
    tag.src = src;
    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(tag);
  }
```

Not working the API says that settings are invalids.

Also tried to do :

```
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-all/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Cryptocurrency Markets</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-screener.js" async>
  {
  "width": 1000,
  "height": 490,
  "defaultColumn": "overview",
  "screener_type": "crypto_mkt",
  "displayCurrency": "USD",
  "colorTheme": "light",
  "transparency": false,
  "locale": "en"
}
  </script>
</div>')
```

which work but is not dynamic ...

I expect the output to be the widget with dynamic use.

Would love if someone can point me my mistakes on this :)

Comment: You could try to rewrite this code as a React component, but I’m afraid the widget itself also loads a script which isn’t compatible with React.

Comment: @Kokodoko aw I see ... But when I load it with the loadScript() function it display the widget but with the default settings (so not what I want) but at least something load. The issu is passing the arguments `{
  "width": 1000,
  "height": 490,
  "defaultColumn": "overview",
  "screener_type": "crypto_mkt",
  "displayCurrency": "USD",
  "colorTheme": "light",
  "transparency": false,
  "locale": "en"
}` to the script. Do u have an idea on how to pass them ?

Comment: Did you try to add innerHTML to the script tag containing the configuration,
something like : `tag.innerHTML = '{ ... config.object ... }'` before setting the src ?

Comment: This is working !!!! Many thanks :D  
added `tag.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);` and this works well :)